# rails 4 array map to change array limiters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following array

```
test = ["0-1000", "5001-15000", "15001-25000"]
```

I tried

```
test.combination(1).to_a
```

This gives

```
[["0-1000"], ["5001-15000"], ["15001-25000"]]
```

But actually expected result is

```
[[0,1000],[5001 ,15000], [15001, 25000]]
```

How to achieve it

Comment: You don't want a combination, you want to collect the split numeric values.

Comment: ["0-1000", "5001-15000", "15001-25000"].collect{|x| x.split('-')}

Comment: Although it's not what you asked for.